# Rewrite rule for url shortening

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed Yourls in my domain under a subdirectory
The service works on its place. 
A working url is http://mydomain.com/1/abc where 1 is the subdirectory.

Is there a way to make a rule to be able to call http://mydomain.com/1abc to resolve to the working url http://mydomain.com/1/abc ?

I don´t quite understand where to put it and how to setup the rule, since I am not sending parameters.

Thanks

Comment: does the abc change? Is that supposed to be unique also are there any other rules that come with yourls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the subdirectory always consists of numbers, and the subdirectory is a physical directory, make a file `.htaccess` in your www-root and add the following to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)[^/]*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)([^/]*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

It first checks if the url matches `^([0-9]+)([^/]*)$` (starts with 1 or more numbers, and contains any non-slash character after that. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)[^/]*$` matches the same thing, because we need the supposed directory-part in the next condition. `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d` checks if the number we think is a subdirectory, is actually a directory. If that is the case, the url will be internally rewritten to `/number/restoftheurl`.